# Best way to install Kitchen Shelves next to existing cabinet?

Tags: kitchens, drill, shelving, storage

To increase storage space, I want to install 3 shelves (above each other) near the edge of my kitchen cabinet, and near the edge of the wall, and above the kitchen ceramic.

Each shelf is about 75cm wide, 25cm deep, while the space between the kitchen cabinet and the wall is about 80cm.

At first I thought about using normal shelf holders, which are about 15cm*20cm,
but this means the first shelf will be at least 15cm above the ceramic, making the upper shelves even harder to reach.

Then I thought about using shelf holders at in the attached photo, but it seems like I won't be able to drill a hole for them, because I can't place the drill so close to the cabinet/wall, as far as I can tell there's no way to drill this close to the cabinet, at least not with a normal drill.

What are my best options? Perhaps using a normal shelf holder that is small than 15cm*20cm, but what is the small I can use without risking the shelves from crashing?

It is a Cement wall. I suppose it's made from blocks.

The kitchen is part of the living room, so I do want a solution that also looks elegant.

[image][image]

Answer (score 2):

A somewhat *standard* (pun intended) way to do this is with [standards](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-48-in-White-Super-Duty-Dual-Track-Wall-Standard-EB-0119-48WT/204611782):

[image: Standard shelve brackets]

Standards are used with shelf brackets designed to fit in the slots. Just make sure (same for the "shelf holders") that the standards are screwed into either studs (typical US construction) or into walls in an appropriate, secure manner. I wouldn't recommend (I have an anecdote from almost 40 years ago) using hollow wall anchors if the shelves will have books, canned goods or anything else heavy.

A big plus is that you can adjust the shelves, so if you start with the bottom shelf very low and later decide you want more workspace below the shelf, you can move it up a few notches.

Comment: The kitchen is part of the living room, so I do want a solution that also looks elegant. this idea might be practical, but there is something too massive about it visibility wise :)

Comment: great proposal for the basement or Garage

Answer (score 1):

Do not use a shelf holder on the lower shelf. Instead, use legs (short pieces of dowel for example) and a small right angle bracket (fastened to the middle of the top of the lower shelf) just to keep it from sliding around. For the second shelf up, and all subsequent shelves, you can use the shelf holders you first mentioned.

Comment: Can you please find some photo that depicts how is it supposed to look?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what strength the wall has there are few options.

First of all I assume you want the shelf to look like part of the kitchen cabinets, and not like some ugly contraption.

In that case I would not use the "**Standard**" proposal. Granted it is quick and dirty proposal that you have to look at all day long.

It just looks very ugly.

Since you have solid wall (not drywall), bricks or cement you can opt for Hidden Shelf type.

There are to many to choose from so you decide.

There are some with the rood in the shelf, and others with the rood under the shelf. In both cases barley visuable.

There are many solutions so look for (floating/Hidden shelf hardware)

Example:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I do want it to look elegant and match the cabinet. The shelves are already in the same wood color as the cabinet. The wall is not drywall, it's a standard wall. Can you please find some photo that depicts the suggested solution? Thanks!

Comment: @Stackaloo see my updated post with picture example

Comment: "standard wall" in the US *is* drywall. Please define what you mean by "standard" wall: brick? block? plaster/lath? something else?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Cement wall. I suppose it's made from blocks.

Comment: @Ruskes It's still not very clear to me. In the photo, Do those shelves have a hole inside them, so the "legs" slide and lock into the holes?  
If so, why should the shelves have rounded corners? and what does it mean to cut strips of wood? the shelf is already made from wood. and attach them how? with screws? does the photo you attach represent the original solution you suggested or is it another one?

Comment: @Stackaloo those do have holes and do not require wood strips on the wall, but there are others in same group that mount differently just google `floating/Hidden shelf hardware)`

Comment: @Stackaloo since you upvoted two other answers I assume you are happy with those.

Comment: @Ruskes Unless you have magical Moderator powers, you don't know who upvoted an anaswer.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact just waiting for you to DV so I can delete it

Comment: I down vote answers that I see as unsafe or have other serious problems. I don't down vote as revenge. I don't down vote because an answer calls my answer ugly. I actually up vote some of your answers, but you'd have no way to know that as votes are secret in this system. Many, many answers from many people I don't up or down vote as I don't feel strongly one way or another.

Comment: @Ruskes I can't upvote any answer because I have a new account. I like your answer the most so far, even though I'm still not sure if that's the way I'll go. I wonder if there are cons to the hidden shelf method?

Comment: @Stackaloo do not worry about that, I just gave you some points anyway for been cooperative. The only con I can think of with hidden shelf would be the load capacity. So do not put all your pots and pans on it. Since it is open space I would mostly place decorative looking stuff like marmalade jars ect..